# Can't pass an ArrayList<Parcelable> to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parameters, parcelable

This is the code

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
list.add(new MyObject());
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiverActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("list", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
List<MyObject> list = (List<MyObject>)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("list");
```

Here list is null. Also this doesn't work:

```
List<MyObject> list = (List<MyObject>)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("list");
```

MyObject is Parcelable, I implemented all required methods. I guess this implementation is not the problem, because otherwise I would recive other kind of exceptions. But I don't get anything besides list is null.

Thanks in advance...

Now I found this:

```
List<Parcelable> list = (List<Parcelable>)getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
```

that has to be used in the receiver activity, but how do I send it and how do I get `List<MyObject>` from `List<Parcelable>` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

USe `i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(name, value)` where i is your intent. Dont use putExtra() for a parcelable ArrayList.

Comment: The method getParcelableArrayListExtra gives me ArrayList<Parcelable> how do I get ArrayList<MyObject> ? Seems like I have to cast on the elements, or instantiate a new copy with type ArrayList<MyObject>?

Comment: your objects must be implementing Parcelable. So they should do fine

Comment: It's not possible to cast them because they are in a List and generics are not covariant.

Comment: do u mean that in order to pass Parcelable array through intent ,we must use static arrays instead of generic list ?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myList = extras.<MyObject>getParcelableArrayList("list"));
```

Comment: Just as a side note. For the intent itself it is intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("name")