# Null receiving Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't pass an ArrayList<Parcelable> to an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190191/cant-pass-an-arraylistparcelable-to-an-activity)

I got this working yesterday, I made some reorganizing in Code and now something is not working anymore. Looking at it a while already and I can't find the problem.

I'm passing an ArrayList of Parcelables to an activity:

```
ArrayList<MyParcelable> myArrayListOfParcelables = new ArrayList<MyParcelable>();

//...

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseGiftDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.FOO, myArrayListOfParcelables);
startActivity(intent);
```

Receiver:

```
ArrayList<Parcelable> parcelableList = (ArrayList<Parcelable>)getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.FOO);
```

parcelableList is always null although I'm sending one.

MyParcelable of course extends Parcelable. I already tested passing one object of MyParcelable using `putExtra`, it always works:

```
Parcelable p = (Parcelable)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(Constants.BAR);
```

or

```
MyParcelable p = (MyParcelable)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(Constants.BAR);
```

I put some debug messages in MyParcelable's code, I see when passing the list only the writting methods are executed but it never starts reading and not even `createFromParcel` is executed. What is this?

Comment: follow this tut http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work

Comment: them you must be missing something

Comment: oh really... I also guess that... that's why I opened this thread

Comment: oh yeah how i just forgot that you hae asked 3 question about parceble interface. and you have still things missing. ;-) where is your class which is implementing parceble inteface

Comment: it's just the most complicated and error-prone way I have ever seen to pass parameters to a different screen. it's absurd I have to spend hours getting this to work and in other plattform I just have to pass a variable...... And you don't even get clear error messages, only things like "Getting Unmarshalling unknown type code" (Unmarshalling what? Which field?) or the object is just null, not warning or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a CREATOR, if not please create one. Then I would try it like this:

```
ArrayList<MyParcelable> myArrayListOfParcelables = new ArrayList<MyParcelable>();

//...

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseGiftDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putIntExtra(Constants.FOO_COUNT, myArrayListOfParcelables.size());
MyParcelable p;
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayListOfParcelables.size(); i++){
    p = myArrayListOfParcelables.get(i);
    intent.putParcelableExtra(Constants.FOO + "_" + i, p);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

then again read it like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int cnt = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.FOO_COUNT);
ArrayList<MyParcelable> myArrayListOfParcelables = new ArrayList<MyParcelable>(cnt);
MyParcelable p;
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
    p = (MyParcelable)intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.FOO + "_" + i);
    myArrayListOfParcelables.add(p);
}
```

This way you have the abillity to see better whats going on under the hood. It may be the case that the Array of Your Parcelables is just too big to get Parceled. I tried once passing a Bitmap and have similar issues.

Comment: hm... ok, this will be the next thing I'll try.